# Websocket send not working from phone network

Tags: ruby, sockets, heroku, websocket

I have a game based on websockets for real-time. With WIFI everything is working as expected. But over phone network, the connection is opened but messages aren't received on the server. While the server pings are received at the client. I am using websocket implementation on heroku using ruby/sinatra for the server and my client is an android app using a websocket library.

This behavior only happens from a 3G phone network and not WIFI.
I have read about websockets not working from phone network because of proxy servers used by phone network providers, then how come I receive the pings from the server? Please help.

Comment: This is a well known problem with WebSockets on some mobile providers. Are you running the WebSocket over unsecured HTTP?

Comment: @Drenmi Yes I am running via unsecured HTTP, is that the problem? Can it be resolved if I try via SSL (wss)

Comment: That is very likely to work, yes, so definitely worth a shot. :-)

Comment: @Drenmi Thanks lot! Will surely try that. For my understanding, can you please explain, how it would help?

Comment: I actually don't have enough source material to write a full fledged answer, but it is mentioned, for example, in the first point of Sam Saffron's [recent article](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2015/12/29/websockets-caution-required) on WebSockets.

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi ! It worked by using wss:// instead of ws://

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by passing it over SSL. I used wss:// instead of ws:// and it worked fine even over phone network.